# Unity5 OVRInput not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

I'm programming in Unity 5.5 and I have all of the up-to-date Oculus utilities needed, but Unity no longer recognizes any inputs from the touch controllers. In the past this has worked fine and I can still get the position and rotation of the controllers but now, if I were to do anything like

```
void Update()
{
    if(OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.RawButton.A)
        Debug.Log("A button pressed");
}
```

Nothing will happen. I've tried every sort of OVRInput there is.

Is anyone else having the same issue or is there something I am missing??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should ensure you have an OVRManager component in your scene, it is a singleton. Attach it to your character gameObject and inputs will work just fine.

Comment: Thank you!!! I don't know why, in the past, I have never attached OVRManager to anything and the inputs used to work fine. Very happy to have full control of my touch controllers again. Thank you!

Comment: A little explanation how to do that would be nice. I found out it comes with the `OVRCameraRig`-Prefab. When you add that to your scene, the buttons start to work. See [this link](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/latest/concepts/unity-utilities-overview/). You can load it by importing the `OculusUtilities.unitypackage` into unity.

Comment: It is not mandatory to use the OVRCameraRig prefab in your scene (in case you may your custom hierarchy Camera/Character). you can just add OVRManager component to any gameObject in your scene and buttons will start to work.

Answer (score 4):

You have to call this function "OVRInput.Update();" before checking the inputs

```
OVRInput.Update();

if (OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.One)) {
    print("One button pressed");
}
```

Comment: I do not know why your comment was downvoted, both your solution and Omar's resolve the issue. I'm upvoting you to offset whatever grinch poopood on you.

Comment: This works, but the solution above requires no changes to any code.